# I want to use MS Power Point and Excel In Ubuntu

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

For my office work, I want to use MS Power Point and MS Excel. I want to know if Microsoft Office is compatible with Ubuntu? If yes, how can I install it? 
If it is not compatible then what is the alternate to MS Office?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with LibreOffice which is compatible.
There are other options also... WPS is a fine office suite and can be downloaded [HERE](http://wps-community.org/)